# UITableView: how implement only one row different from the others

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uistoryboard

in Storyboard (in Xcode 6) i want design a view like this
[user profile view](http://cdn.pttrns.com/pttrns/3121/original/IMG_0667.PNG)

The rows are dynamic because the content is get from a web services. How can i implement this view?

I have tried with an image view (the upper image with user name and pic) with a table view below but when i scroll the table obviously scroll only the table.

The image in the link is a uitableview with only the first row different from the other? How can implement only one row different from the other?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take two custom cells give different identifiers .one for only your first row and other for n-1 cells.

and  load cellForRowATIndexPath as

before that take one temporary array

```
NSArray *arr=[[NSArra alloc]initWithObjects:@"FirstIdentifer",@"SecondIdientfier"];

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 NSString *CellIdentifier = [self.menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([CellIdentifier isEqualToString:@"FirstIdentifer"]) {
        Mycell *cell = (Mycell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TempCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
//do your stuff

        return  cell;

    }

    else
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SecondIdientfier";

    cell1 = (Mycell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Mycell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell1 = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    //do your stuff


 return cell1;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That view could either be a `tableHeaderView` which does scroll with the table, or a cell. You can create as many prototype cells in the table view as you want, and give them different reuse identifiers. In cellForRowATIndexPath, put in an if-else clause, and dequeue whichever cell you want based on the indexPath.row.